# How to run JUnit on the command line?

Tags: java, junit, command-line, executable-jar

I'm running a small lab on a directory (`Lab7`) with the following subdirectories:

- bin
- lib
- src
- test

I need to compile my test file using the jar file in `/lib` and have its class redirect to the `/bin` directory. I also then need to figure out how to run it as well. This all has to be on the command line so I can't use anything like Maven/Gradle. I know the imports are fine because this is an old lab I'm looking back on, but the commands to compile and run were provided so we never had to learn that part.

I can compile my src file just fine and have its class redirect to /bin. However when I try to compile my test file with:

```
javac -cp .:lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar .\test\TestFile.java
```

I receive an error:

```
error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
```

followed by all cannot find symbol errors.